# Java Home not set

Tags: java, gradle, system-properties

I downloaded gradle and in the instruction it told me to add it to system variables so i did but i accidentally removed one of the paths. So when i tried to see what version of gradle i use it was saying error java home is not set(you can see in the image in the mingv terminal). My question is how can i set up my java home here is an image where is showing the paths that i have and on the right what its saying on terminal.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your screenshot presents list of `PATH` variable values. Close this dialog.

On the parent dialog window, add new variable, name it `JAVA_HOME`.

Put the following value to it: `C:\Program Files\jdk-18.0.1`

Click OK to accept your changes

[image: screenshot]

Comment: i need to add JAVA_HOME to user variables or system ?

Comment: I would add it to the System section

Comment: Glad to help you. Please mark this answer as accepted (green mark just below the votes count) to help others find this information easily.

Answer (score 1):

Click on 'new'. Type "JAVA_HOME" inside variable name and type path for the java bin folder on variable value.

The result will be as below

[System variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zDYrt.png)